# Snowflake: Unsupported feature '1'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view that was built utilizing a new feature of snowflake - [unstructured data](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-launches-unstructured-data-support-in-public-preview/)

I can query the view without any problem, but when I put it in CTE I get an error - Unsupported feature '1'.

e.g.

```
with unstructured_view as (
    select *
    from "ANALYTICS"."UNSTRUCTERED_VIEW"
)

select * 
from unstructured_view
```

error message:

> Unsupported feature '1'

Maybe someone knows how to deal with it?

Comment: Congratulations, you seem to have found a bug/unimplemented feature. Check the release notes.

Comment: I'd recommend you get your query_id and open a Snowflake Support Case, they should be able to assist you while looking into the details of your underlying objects and such.  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Comment: Are you using Streams over Directory Tables? If yes, try to rewrite it without using the CTE, it might help.